# How do I get the response from an HTTP request on error?

Tags: apache-flex, http, actionscript, networking

I tried using both `HTTPService` and `URLRequest`/`URLLoader`. But I can't figure out how to get either the response output or the response headers in case of a server error(like 500). Some help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listening to the HTTPStatusEvent should give you the right status code, but you won't have access to the response body.

You need to do this through sockets.

[This projects](http://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient/tree/master) encapsulates requests through sockets, giving you access to the status code, body response and other niceties (making PUT and DELETE requests, for example).

Note that since flash player 10, using sockets will require additional steps regarding crossdomains.

Cheers

Comment: yikes, that's what I was afraid of.